# how to get id from url in cake php

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

This is my action URL of which I'd like to get the *16*.

```
http://localhost/carsdirectory/Galleries/add/16
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$this->params['pass']
```

Returns an array (numerically indexed) of URL parameters after the Action.

```
// URL: /posts/view/12/print/narrow      
Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => print
    [2] => narrow
)
```

Another Method is - Just pass the parameter to the function itself like as follows:

```
function add($id=null)
{
   echo $id;
}
```

this will return your id

Comment: And if I need to print `print` and `narrow` too, will it be like `function add($id=null,$print=null,$narrow=null) { echo $print;echo $null; }`

Answer (score -1):

Sorry i'm not familliar with phpcake but you Can use `Regular Expression`
See Attached Links
[Php Perform Regular Expression](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)
[CakePhp Custom Regular Expression Validation](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1180/Custom-Regular-Expression-Validation)

Comment: How does this help? It has nothing to do with the question. He's trying to get the id from the URL.